# Unable to access selenium webdriver IWebdriver interface in Visual Studio Code c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written basic c# script to invoke chrome browser using selenium webdriver in Visual Studio Code. **The machine doesn't have access to internet**.I have manually added nuget selenium webdriver/chrome and newtonsoft packages to the project file. But, when I try use OpenQA.Selenium, it doesn't show the reference(using intellisense) and hence can't invoke IWebdriver instance. Can some one please guide me why I'm not able to use the package in spite of adding webdriver reference?

> Below is the csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
<RestoreSources>../Downloads/pkg- 
webdriver/selenium.webdriver/3.141.0</RestoreSources>
<RestoreSources>../Downloads/pkg- 
newton/newtonsoft.json/10.0.3</RestoreSources>
<RestoreSources>../Downloads/pkg- 
chrome/selenium.chrome.webdriver/2.45.0</RestoreSources>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="newtonsoft.json" Version="10.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="selenium.chrome.webdriver" Version="2.45" />
<PackageReference Include="selenium.webdriver" Version="3.141.0" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

> Below is the script:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium; --Can't import this package
namespace NAS
{
class Program
{
    static IWebdriver driver;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Output of dotnet restore:

```
 Restoring packages for /Users/admin/NAS/NAS.csproj...
 Restore completed in 223.99 ms for /Users/admin/NAS/NAS.csproj.
```

> Build and clean:

```
armagnac:NAS admin$ **dotnet clean**
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Build started 25/02/2019 09:08:41.
1>Project "/Users/admin/NAS/NAS.csproj" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
1>CoreClean:
     Creating directory "obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/".
1>Done Building Project "/Users/admin/NAS/NAS.csproj" (Clean target(s)).
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.51
armagnac:NAS admin$ **dotnet build**
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Restore completed in 33.86 ms for /Users/admin/NAS/NAS.csproj.
NAS -> /Users/admin/NAS/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/NAS.dll
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:01.23
```

Comment: Clean solution and rebuild again..either remove and download nuget package from nuget manager.

Comment: @Dhru'soni , thank you. I performed 'dotnet clean' and then 'dotnet build', both succeeded, but still can't import webdriver. Sorry, nuget manager is not installed as it doesn't have internet connection. I have used command line(dotnet add package) to install the packages.